# use dos set variables in if statement to set the ip address of a machine

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I am trying to use the variables from the set command in dos, namely the %computername% to set a static IP address for a machine or two.  I am a bit crap at writing code, so I have broken it down into simple steps, but don't know how to code it in dos, or perhaps powershell even, and would appreciate some help/guidance.

1. echo %computername% (this gives an output of the local hostname, say PC201, but could be 202 or 203 )
2. if %computername% = pc201 then netsh interface ipv4 set address name -"Ethernet0" static 192.168.110.11 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.254 goto end
3. if %computername% = pc202 then netsh interface ipv4 set address name -"Ethernet0" static 192.168.110.12 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.254 goto end
4. if %computername% = pc203 then netsh interface ipv4 set address name -"Ethernet0" static 192.168.110.13 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.254 goto end

:end exit

I can get the netsh command to set the ip, if i use a variable %1 on the last octet of the IP address, for example setip.bat 11 so I know I can pass a variable, but I am unable to pull the variable from an echo statement

echo %computername% outputs
PC201, but I dont know how to get this name decide what IP to give it, from a list perhaps of PC names and IPs I want to assign

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a PC/IP list. For the example I generate one:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,5) do @echo PC20%i,192.168.110.10%i>>"PC-IP List.csv"
```

Check the content:

```
type "PC-IP List.csv"

PC201,192.168.110.101
PC202,192.168.110.102
PC203,192.168.110.103
PC204,192.168.110.104
PC205,192.168.110.105
```

Assign the IP:
(for safty here I only echo the command instead to execute it. Remove the "echo" for real usage)

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %a in ("PC-IP List.csv") do @if "%a" == "%COMPUTERNAME%" (echo netsh interface ipv4 set address name -"Ethernet0" static %b 192.168.100.254)
```

`tokens=1,2` tells to use item 1 and 2 from the list.

`delims=,` tells the items are separated by a `,`

`%a` says, the first item will be stored in **%a** the second item will be stored in the alphabeticaly next name **%b**

`usebackq` switches to the newer syntax within the brackets after the "in", so filenames with spaces can be used (and more).

`("File Name")` Used like this (or without double quotes) the file content will be evaluated (influenced by 'usebackq').

When using this within a batch, you have to double the %a => %%a (the shell "eats" one of them)
Sightly extended the batch can look like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (%1) do (
    @if /i "%%a" == "%COMPUTERNAME%" (
        echo Found:  %%a - Assigning IP %%b;
        echo netsh interface ipv4 set address name -"Ethernet0" static %%b 192.168.100.254
    )
)
```

*Edit: Extended the `if` clause in the batch script to ignore the case of %COMPUTERNAME% at comparison.*

This batch takes the filename of the CSV-List as the first parameter:

```
script.bat "PC-IP List.csv"
```

Please note:

- *Also here the demo only echos the final command. Remove the "echo" in front of the "netsh" to activate the final command execution.*
- *While testing disable the @echo off to see what the script does.*
- *I did not verify or test the netsh command. It's a copy of your sample in the question.*

You can get more details at the buildin help by typing `for /?` and `if /?`

Comment: Lo dodrg, thanks for that help.  I edited the batch file so that it was working, and I spent  a long time trying to figure out why the script wouldnt pick up the IP address assigned.  I used an echo command at different stages, and I could see where the command got stuck.  Eventually I realised that the variable %computername% is case sensitive, as in DOS the name of the host is in CAPs, but in the script I had it lowercase. So changing the names in the CSV to CAPs fixed that.

Comment: You can extend the `if` clause to  `if /i` to let it ignore the case. — I updated my batch sample.

Comment: Is  your problem solved by this?